# Вызов внутренней функции

Tags: oracle, plsql

В определенной процедуре в пакете есть внутренняя функция описанная в `declare`  разделe этой процедуры.

Есть какая-либо возможность вызвать эту функцию извне, или она может быть вызвана только этой процедурой?

Comment: Нет, только внутри процедуры. Как, собственно, почти везде.

Comment: А не подскажете, для чего обычно используют вложение функций и процедур? Чтобы защитить их от внешних вызовов или есть еще какие - то особенности? В плане практики применения можно что - то почитать )) ?

Comment: Чтобы защитить от внешнего вызова в пакете, достаточно не объявлять функцию в интерфейсной части. Обычно все прозаичнее - есть кусок кода, который повторяется, но нужен только внутри одной функции. Можно прямо внутри нее и объявить, чтобы пространство имен не занимать почем зря.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, вызвать извне функцию, объявленную внутри другой функции нельзя. Поиск подпрограммы для вызова производится начиная с текущего пространства имён и продолжается, если не найдена, последовательно в пространствах имён уровнем выше.
См. [*How PL/SQL Compiler Resolves Invocations* в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00808).

Это вполне нормально, объявить функцию только в том пространстве имён, где она впервые применяется (в пакетной процедуре, как в данном случае), и тем самым ограничить её область видимости и избежать возможных конфликтов имён.

Если надо вызвать функцию также в программном блоке где она пока не видна и избежать тем самым дупликатов кода, то необходим рефакторинг кода. Переместите функцию в пространство имен, где она будет доступна для вызова из нового и старого кода, возможно переименуйте её.

Например:

```
create or replace package pkg as
    function foo (arg number) return number;
end pkg;
/
create or replace package body pkg as
    function bar (arg number) return number is
        factor constant number := 10;
    begin 
        return arg * factor;
    end;
    function foo (arg number) return number is
        /** original bar was moved to the package scope */
        function bar (arg number) return number is
        begin 
            return pkg.bar (arg);
        end;
    begin 
        return foo.bar (arg);
    end;
end pkg;
/
```